# Private content for a JS script only, without rendering a HTML template

Tags: magento2, javascript, full-page-cache, renderer

There is a lot of articles, blogs and stackexchange posts about inserting private content into a HTML template with knockout and data-bindings. And I know how to do that.

But...

How to use Magento2's private content feature to pass some data to a JS script only? Not to any template, no knockout, no data-binding, no rendering HTML.

Let's say I want to call or not to call a method of a JS object - depending on a value returned as some private content.

I was searching Google for a whole 2 day and I couldn't find an answer.

I thought about calling my JS like below:

```js
// ...
return Component.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this._super();
    if (customerData.get('my_data')) {
      myObject.foobar(true);
    }
  }
});
// ...
```

But I'm not sure if it's a good (Magento standard) way to go. I feel I'm missing something.

Do I really need then to create a phtml file whose sole purpose is to insert `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`, without any renderable HTML?

Thanks in advance for all ideas.

Comment: Even the customer-data component you are using in your example, is declared the same way :)

`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/customer-data.phtml`

Comment: @DanStaver Indeed, it is :) So I looked in every place but the source. I think you could write your comment as the answer.

Comment: :) Also, I like to use the ifconfig property inside the block declaration, inside the block declaration. Like an example: 

`<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="newsletter_head_components" template="Magento_Newsletter::js/components.phtml" ifconfig="newsletter/general/active"/>`

So, this block will be output only if setting is enabled in the admin panel, no need for extra method to check that